# adicionar items num arquivo json em tempo real

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Olá, eu estou programando uma especie de assistente virtual em node e fiz um código pra o usuário adicionar possíveis comandos, isso ele salva o comando em um arquivo JSON, mas queria deixar pra que ele salve logo apos ser informado pelo usuário.Abaixo segue uma parte desse código:

```
var mind = function(){

function jsonReader(filePath, cb) {
    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8', (err, fileData) =>{
        if (err) {
            return cb && cb(err);
        }
        try {
            const object = JSON.parse(fileData);
            return cb && cb(null, object);
        } catch (err) {
            return cb && cb(err);
        }
    });
}

let ques = readlineSync.question('Quest to learn: ');
let res  = readlineSync.question('Response to back: ');

const newObject =
{
    quest: ques, // variavel em que foi escrito a palavra
    response: res
}; 

//chamar o arquivo para assim salvar os objetos em seu conteúdo
fs.readFile("./memory/content.json", "utf8", (err, res)=> {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    } else {

        var data = JSON.parse(res);

        var dataArray = data.push(newObject);

        try {
            fs.writeFileSync('./memory/content.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
            console.log("Salvo com sucesso!");
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    };
});
```

}

O formato que tá salvando no JSON é o seguinte:

[
{
"nome":"Cleitin",
"idade":23
}
]

Caso consigam me ajudar em algo,agradeço muito. (atualizei)

Comment: Sem mais detalhes e sobre o erro e como é o formato desse JSON fica difícil ajudar....

Comment: Bem, não tem nenhum erro em si, o negócio é que ele só salva no arquivo, quando fecha o programa rodando no terminal

Answer (score -3):

Inferindo que seu Json tem essa estrutura:

```
{
 data: []
}
```

Veja se isso te ajuda.

```
const fs = require("fs");

const filePath = "./arquivo.json";
const newObject = {
  name: "novo objeto 1",
};

fs.readFile(filePath, addNewItem);

function addNewItem(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log("error", err);
  let json = JSON.parse(data);
  json.data.push(newObject);
  fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(json), (err, result) => {
    if (err) console.log("error", err);
  });
}
```